# As you can pass params from one action to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As you can pass params from one action to another?

```
#In this action the user passes the parameters of the credit card
def review
  @cart = current_cart

  ...
  ...
end
```

This action displays the sum of the order etc. And a Button that the user can confirm the order. If he will confirm, then the parameters must be passed in the model where the payment will be made.

```
def update
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.update_attributes(params[:cart])

  Purchasing.purchase(current_user, current_cart, credit_card)
end


class Purchasing
  def initialize(user, cart, credit_card)
    @user = user
    @cart = cart
    @credit_card = credit_card
  end

  #This method of payment order.
  def purchase
    begin
      result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
          amount: @cart.total,
          credit_card: {
            number: ??',
            cvv: ??,
            expiration_month: ??,
            expiration_year: ??
          }
      )

    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you please clarify and rephrase the question?

Comment: This code has no right to work, purchase is an instance method, and you are calling a class method.

Comment: I am confused as to what the question is as well but Purchasing.purchase(current_user, current_cart, credit_card) needs to be Purchasing.new(current_user, current_cart, credit_card).purchase.

Comment: @Tacoman667 `Purchasing.new(current_user, current_cart, credit_card).purchase` credit_card==nil How do I get these params from method of `review`

Comment: `params[:credit_card]`? I don't know where you are storing, grabbing, passing that variable in the first place.

Comment: @Tacoman667 please see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vadus1/3bac6430b8c7e4ef3c48)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in params[] you will see the credit_card values. You will need to reference them individually instead of through `params[:credit_card]`. `params[:name]`, `params[:cvv]`, `params[:expiration_month]`, `params[:expiration_year]` are all available. Pass these individually or create a credit_card class to store them in to pass to the method.

```
Purchasing.new(current_user, current_cart, CreditCard.new(name: params[:name], cvv: params[:cvv], <and_so_on>)).purchase
```

Comment: They need to be. Pass them inside the form. The nature of the web is stateless. It doesn't know anything unless it's told in the requests or pulled from a persistent store.

Comment: Well, of course. Damn I did not pass these parameters from the form. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def update
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.update_attributes(params[:cart])

  this_purchase = Purchasing.new (current_user, current_cart, credit_card)
  this_purchase.purchase
end
```

Comment: the question is how to get the parameters `credit_card`?  the question is how to get the parameters `credit_card`? In method `review` we fill the form and pass the parameters of the credit card method `review`. But the parameters required for the method `update`

Comment: Doesn't `@credit_card` have all that data? so then `credit_card: { name: @credit_card.name, <blahblah> }`

Comment: @Tacoman667 Yes, this is true. But `@credit_card.name == nil`